# Getting a variable from a multidimentional JSON array using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am retrieving a multidimensional JSON array using JQUERY.

I need to print out various items from the array, but am having a hard time figuring out how to go through the array and get these items so I can insert them into the HTML.

Here is an example of the array (this is what is taken from the jsonpage.php referenced below.

```
{
   "count":1,
   "total_count":1,
   "contacts":[
      {
         "id":92840643,
         "user_id":55536,
         "first_name":"John",
         "last_name":"Doe",
         "full_name":"John  Doe",
         "initials":"JD",
         "title":null,
         "company":null,
         "email":"john@doe.com",
         "avatar":"https://graph.facebook.com/123454/picture?type=large",
         "avatar_url":"https://graph.facebook.com/123454/picture?type=large",
         "last_contacted":null,
         "visible":true,
         "twitter":null,
         "facebook_url":null,
         "linkedin_url":null,
         "first_contacted":null,
         "created_at":"2014-05-26T19:06:55Z",
         "updated_at":"2014-05-26T19:12:42Z",
         "hits":0,
         "user_bucket_id":486405,
         "team_parent_id":null,
         "snoozed_at":null,
         "snooze_days":null,
         "groupings":[
            {
               "id":21554286,
               "type":"Grouping::Location",
               "name":"Johnson, NY",
               "stub":"frisco tx",
               "bucket_id":null,
               "user_id":55536,
               "domain_id":null,
               "editable":null,
               "conversable":null,
               "locked":null,
               "derived_from_id":null
            },
            {
               "id":21553660,
               "type":"Grouping::Bucket",
               "name":"Top Customers",
               "stub":"top customers",
               "bucket_id":486405,
               "user_id":55536,
               "domain_id":null,
               "editable":null,
               "conversable":null,
               "locked":null,
               "derived_from_id":null,
               "has_followups":true,
               "num_days_to_followup":30,
               "program_id":null
            }
         ],
         "email_addresses":[
            "john@doe.com"
         ],
         "tags":[

         ],
         "contact_status":3,
         "team_last_contacted":null,
         "team_last_contacted_by":null,
         "phone_numbers":[

         ],
         "addresses":[
            {
               "_id":"538390cfcc0fb067d8000353",
               "created_at":"2014-05-26T19:06:55Z",
               "deleted_at":null,
               "extra_data":{
                  "address_city":"Johnson",
                  "address_state":"NY",
                  "address_country":"United States"
               },
               "label":"Address",
               "primary":null,
               "remote_id":null,
               "updated_at":"2014-05-26T19:06:55Z",
               "username":null,
               "value":"Johnson, NY\nUnited States"
            }
         ],
         "social_profiles":[

         ],
         "websites":[

         ],
         "custom_fields":[
            {
               "_id":"538390cfcc0fb067d8000354",
               "custom_field_id":46639,
               "deleted_at":null,
               "label":"WeeklyNews",
               "value":"YES"
            },
            {
               "_id":"538390cfcc0fb067d8000355",
               "custom_field_id":46640,
               "deleted_at":null,
               "label":"Current Credits",
               "value":"142"
            },
            {
               "_id":"538390cfcc0fb067d8000356",
               "custom_field_id":46641,
               "deleted_at":null,
               "label":"Total Purchased Amount",
               "value":"400"
            },
            {
               "_id":"538390cfcc0fb067d8000357",
               "custom_field_id":46642,
               "deleted_at":null,
               "label":"VDownloads",
               "value":"112"
            },
            {
               "_id":"538390cfcc0fb067d8000358",
               "custom_field_id":46643,
               "deleted_at":null,
               "label":"AEDownloads",
               "value":"9"
            },
            {
               "_id":"538390cfcc0fb067d8000359",
               "custom_field_id":46644,
               "deleted_at":null,
               "label":"ADownloads",
               "value":"53"
            },
            {
               "_id":"538390cfcc0fb067d800035a",
               "custom_field_id":46638,
               "deleted_at":null,
               "label":"Last Login",
               "value":"2014-05-25 23:14:19"
            },
            {
               "_id":"538390cfcc0fb067d800035b",
               "custom_field_id":46649,
               "deleted_at":null,
               "label":"Label",
               "value":"Group1"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

And here is the jquery success code:

```
 $.post('/jsonpage.php', post_data,  function(response) {



 });
```

Now, if I put alert(response); within the function i.e.:

```
 $.post('/jsonpage.php', post_data,  function(response) {

 alert(response);
      });
```

Then, it 'does' alert the entire JSON string as listed above.

However, if I put this:

```
 $.post('/jsonpage.php', post_data,  function(response) {

 alert(response.count);
      });
```

Then, I get UNDEFINED in the alert box.  I have tried a few different variables to 'alert' and they all come back undefined.

Thanks for your help!

Craig

Comment: Unless your html page is very complex and you really need everything, imo there is way too much "Stuff" in that json and jsonpage.php should probably trim down that massive blob to something more useful/manageable/not as bandwidth intensive.  But hey, maybe you need it all!

Comment: Thanks James.  I am retrieving it via an API, and you are right.  I don't need it all and I will see how I can limit it down and not get everything back.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and cleaning up my question as well.  I very much appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response.total_count
response.contacts[0].id
response.contacts[0].groupings[0].stub
```

And so on.

Comment: `response` is data, not a DOM element

Comment: Oh, sorry, typo. Edited.

Comment: This looks right, but I am getting UNDEFINED when trying to alert my variables.  Can you check my edits above?

Comment: Try to inspect the response in the Google Developer Tools console, i.e. do a `console.log(response)` and expand the result.

Comment: Can you define "expand the result?"  I did check the console and all of the data shows up there when I just alert(response) and when I alert(response.count) in the same spot, it just says undefined as mentioned above.  Can you let me know what "expanding" does?  Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Do a `console.log(response)` (not an `alert(response)`). Then press CTRL+SHIFT+J in Google Chrome to open up the console. There you will find a row with a plus sign next to it. Expand the row by clicking the plus sign. Then you can inspect the response. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eUP9k/

Comment: Ok, problem solved!!  I had to first do a response=JSON.parse(response)!

Once I did that, everything else worked correctly.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways of using the data in your json response.  Hope it helps.

```
$.post('/jsonpage.php', post_data,  function(response) {

  if (!response.contacts || !response.contacts.length) {
    alert("Error loading that/those contact(s)");
    return;
  }

  for (var i=0, c; c = response.contacts[i]; i++) {
    // c is each contact, do stuff with c
    alert("That contact was created at " + c.created_at + " and last updated at " + c.updated_at);

    var cities = [];

    for (var j=0, a; a = c.addresses[j]; j++) {
      // a refers to each address
      cities.push(a.extra_data.address_city);
    }
    alert(c.full_name + " lives in " + cities.join(" and ") + ".");

    for (var j=0, cf; cf = c.custom_fields[j]; j++) {
      // cf is each custom_field
      // build a form or something
      // element label is cf.label
      // element value is currently cf.value
      var p = document.createElement("p");
      p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cf.label));

      var el = document.createElement("input");
      el.type = "text";
      el.value = cf.value;

      p.appendChild(el);

      document.getElementById("someForm").appendChild(p);

    }

  }

});
```

Comment: Checking this out now James, but thanks for taking the time to post this extra info./details.  Awesomeness!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = { "count": 1, "total_count": 1, "contacts": [{ "id": 92840643, "user_id": 55536, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "full_name": "John  Doe", "initials": "JD", "title": null, "company": null, "email": "john@doe.com", "avatar": "https://graph.facebook.com/123454/picture?type=large", "avatar_url": "https://graph.facebook.com/123454/picture?type=large", "last_contacted": null, "visible": true, "twitter": null, "facebook_url": null, "linkedin_url": null, "first_contacted": null, "created_at": "2014-05-26T19:06:55Z", "updated_at": "2014-05-26T19:12:42Z", "hits": 0, "user_bucket_id": 486405, "team_parent_id": null, "snoozed_at": null, "snooze_days": null, "groupings": [{ "id": 21554286, "type": "Grouping::Location", "name": "Johnson, NY", "stub": "frisco tx", "bucket_id": null, "user_id": 55536, "domain_id": null, "editable": null, "conversable": null, "locked": null, "derived_from_id": null }, { "id": 21553660, "type": "Grouping::Bucket", "name": "Top Customers", "stub": "top customers", "bucket_id": 486405, "user_id": 55536, "domain_id": null, "editable": null, "conversable": null, "locked": null, "derived_from_id": null, "has_followups": true, "num_days_to_followup": 30, "program_id": null}], "email_addresses": ["john@doe.com"], "tags": [], "contact_status": 3, "team_last_contacted": null, "team_last_contacted_by": null, "phone_numbers": [], "addresses": [{ "_id": "538390cfcc0fb067d8000353", "created_at": "2014-05-26T19:06:55Z", "deleted_at": null, "extra_data": { "address_city": "Johnson", "address_state": "NY", "address_country": "United States" }, "label": "Address", "primary": null, "remote_id": null, "updated_at": "2014-05-26T19:06:55Z", "username": null, "value": "Johnson, NY\nUnited States"}], "social_profiles": [], "websites": [], "custom_fields": [{ "_id": "538390cfcc0fb067d8000354", "custom_field_id": 46639, "deleted_at": null, "label": "WeeklyNews", "value": "YES" }, { "_id": "538390cfcc0fb067d8000355", "custom_field_id": 46640, "deleted_at": null, "label": "Current Credits", "value": "142" }, { "_id": "538390cfcc0fb067d8000356", "custom_field_id": 46641, "deleted_at": null, "label": "Total Purchased Amount", "value": "400" }, { "_id": "538390cfcc0fb067d8000357", "custom_field_id": 46642, "deleted_at": null, "label": "VDownloads", "value": "112" }, { "_id": "538390cfcc0fb067d8000358", "custom_field_id": 46643, "deleted_at": null, "label": "AEDownloads", "value": "9" }, { "_id": "538390cfcc0fb067d8000359", "custom_field_id": 46644, "deleted_at": null, "label": "ADownloads", "value": "53" }, { "_id": "538390cfcc0fb067d800035a", "custom_field_id": 46638, "deleted_at": null, "label": "Last Login", "value": "2014-05-25 23:14:19" }, { "_id": "538390cfcc0fb067d800035b", "custom_field_id": 46649, "deleted_at": null, "label": "Label", "value": "Group1"}]}] };
    alert(data["contacts"][0]["id"]);

//get count
alert(data["count"]); //1
//get first contacts data
data["contacts"][0]["id"] //retruns 92840643
//do same for others to get data
```

Comment: I think you've got a typo there: `alert(j["contacts"][0]["id"]);`